# Managed Debugging Assistant(MDA) jitCompilationStart usage

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, optimization

I'm trying to optimize cold startup time of some WinForms application.I've NGen'ed all assemblies but still see that JIT is invoked. I've enabled MDA's jitCompilationStart and see runtime exceptions from MDA saying that something is causing invocation of JIT.

My question is - now what? What I see is list of suggested debuggers. If I choose sthm from list - I see nothing in VS. App continues to execute and that's all. How can I get info about what part of app invokes JIT?

[image]

I've enabled JitCompilationStart in Debug->Exceptions -> Managed Debugging Assistants:

[image]

Comment: Are you running your code under a debugger? From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx: "When an MDA is enabled, it is active even when your code is not executing under a debugger. If an MDA event is raised when a debugger is not present, the event message is presented in an unhandled exception dialog box, although it is not an unhandled exception. To avoid the dialog box, remove the MDA-enabling settings when your code is not executing in a debugging environment."

Comment: @MarcSherman If there is no debugger attached, then there is exception dialog box. If I attach VS to WinForms process on start, then there are no exception dialog boxes and app works without any problems. But I don't see any logs or sthm like that from MDA.

Comment: From reading about the jitCompilationStart MDA is sounds like it only reports JIT events so maybe you successfully got rid of them all. What happens if you run it with VS attached with a version of your program that is not NGen'ed at all? Do you see the JIT events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That MDA was meant to get a debugger attached when the jitter starts.  Requirements are a registered *unmanaged* debugger that is capable of debugging C++ code as well as the source code for the jitter.  You already have the first requirement met, VS20120 and VS2012 have excellent unmanaged debuggers.  The latter one is a rather hard one for mere mortals like you and me.  The entire scenario is only interesting for Microsoft SDETs.

Clearly you are on the wrong path to diagnose cold start delays.  In more than one way, the jitter is a *warm* start detail.  Cold starts are dominated by the time required for the disk to find the assembly files.  Using Ngen is in fact exactly what you *don't* want to do, it doubles the number of files that need to be found.  It is only good to improve warm start times.

There are only three good solutions to cold start delays.  Use less assemblies, ILMerge can help.  Use a faster disk, an SSD helps a lot.  And cheat, start a small do-nothing .NET program at login time that gets the assemblies loaded into the file system cache.  Which is actually automatic after the user has started your .NET app for a while, the [Windows prefetcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefetcher) learns and preloads DLLs.  Hard to notice, other than the customer stopping to complain after a while.

Comment: Thanks, updated question - wrong terminology. Warm startup of course. Anyway why do I see jitCompilationStart output in small spike app with attached VS, but don't see any MDA output in my big app with attached VS. There are MDA exceptions in runtime in big app. Why they are not caught with attached VS?

Comment: Now I've caught exception. Are there are some issues on ngen'ing generic collections?

Comment: You've completely invalidated my answer.  You cannot do that.  Click Ask Question again to ask another question.